# Error in SQL INSERT INTO query

Tags: php, sql

I have following code written in PHP:

```
  $q = mysql_query("INSERT INTO logowania ('user','udane','ip') VALUES ($uid,0,'".ip()."')"); echo mysql_error();
```

Values of `$uid` and `ip()` are correct, you can trust me.

Structure of `logowania` table:

```
1   idlogowania     int(11)             

2   user    int(11) 

3   udane   tinyint(1)  

4   data    timestamp       on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP     CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP     

5   ip  text    utf8_polish_ci
```

I don't know where is the error in the statement. MySQL gives:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''user','udane','ip') VALUES (1,0,'79.184.7.44')' at line 1

I tried to debug that, but without successful ending. I know that could be very simple mistake, but human's vision isn't infallible...

Comment: Use `mysqli_` function family (and prepared statements) instead of using obsolete `mysql_` and building query "by hand".

Comment: @Vyktor I've used `mysql_real_escape_string()` function, before query. I'm sorry, but I hate `mysqli_`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use back ticks for column name,otherwise they are treated as strings.

```
(`user`,`udane`,`ip`)
```

Comment: You were first, so I will accept your answer :-). Now everything works. Thank you for help, that was a stupid error... :-(

Answer (score 1):

Take out '' from the column names.

```
$q = mysql_query("INSERT INTO logowania ('user','udane','ip') VALUES ($uid,0,'".ip()."')"); echo mysql_error();
```

should be

```
$q = mysql_query("INSERT INTO logowania (user,udane,ip) VALUES ($uid,0,'".ip()."')"); echo mysql_error();
```

OR use back-tics for the col names

```
$q = mysql_query("INSERT INTO logowania (`user`,`udane`,`ip`) VALUES ($uid,0,'".ip()."')"); echo mysql_error();
```

Comment: You weren't first, but thanks for your help. Now everything works. Thank you for help, that was a stupid error... :-(

Answer (score 0):

Alternative version:

```
$q = mysql_query("INSERT INTO logowania SET `user` = '" . $uid . "', `udane` = 0, `ip` = '" . ip() . "'"); echo mysql_error();
```